# Legend label rounding with Python in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, legend, cartographic-information-model

In a legend of feature layer, I would like to format the subtitle so that it doesn't print the full number, but rounds the category limits to 2 decimal places. I want to implement the format shown in the image not manually, but within a python script. I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2 version.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr5 = m.addDataFromPath(elev)
sym5 = lyr5.symbology
if hasattr(sym5, 'renderer'):
    if sym5.renderer.type == 'SimpleRenderer':
        sym5.updateRenderer("GraduatedColorsRenderer")
        sym5.renderer.classificationField = "Elevation"
        sym5.renderer.colorRamp = aprx.listColorRamps("Elevation #3")[0]
        sym5.renderer.breakCount = 10
        lyr5.symbology = sym5
```

[image]

Comment: Get the symbology (sym = lyr5.symbology) and loop through the breaks (for brk in sym.renderer.classBreaks:) and edit the labels there?